# Netflix not accessible by Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I've trying to access to Netflix from the computer using Wi-Fi and it's not responding, but accessing via mobile (with the same Wi-Fi) or accessing via another Wi-Fi (using a PLC+Wi-Fi extender connected to the same router) it's working. Other pages are working too.

I've tried to set up a sniffer (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) on the computer and then it's working too! I don't understand what can be wrong. And the firewall is disabled.

What could be the problem?

[More info]: Google works, but YouTube not!

[Update 2]: DNS is the same in both wifi's 8.8.8.8 and doing a nslookup, netflix.com is solved and the error returned is "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET". I can't understand the issue! I've tried on Edge and Internet Explorer too! And with other computer is working in the same wifi too! It must be something about the wifi connection, but I've reseted it and the problem persists.

Comment: Perhaps a firewall issue? Try temporarily to disable the firewall on the computer.

Comment: You might have to give us some details about your operating system. Also, `it's not responding` is somehow vague. Name resolution? Time out? Explicit error from Netflix? Did you try more than one browser?

Comment: Could be a DNS issue, try setting 8.8.8.8 as your primary DNS server on your Wi-Fi connection

Comment: Firewall is disabled.

Comment: Are you using a proxy on your browser for your computer?

Comment: Sorry, I can't try now, but: 1. I wanted to get the error, so I activate fiddler, but then works (I'll get it from chrome developer tools and I'll post it here). 2: I think that's not a DNS issue, because use the default configuration and I think that it must that it must be the same in all the network, but I'll do a nslookup to check it. 3. I'm not using any proxy when fails, and with Fiddler it's working...